# create_event is not a member of the permissions table fbcmd

Tags: linux, facebook, terminal

Excuse me for mistakes. But I'm new here. I have problem with granting additional access to cmdfb. I have got token and approved it. But still I don't have access.

```
@ubuntu:~$ fbcmd showperm
```

fbcmd [v1.1] ERROR: SHOWPERM
[602] create_event is not a member of the permissions table.

Regards

Comment: There is no permission named create_event

Answer (score 1):

WizKid is right; that permission does not exist (anymore).

Since version v2.x of the Graph API it's not possible anymore to programmatically create events. For existing permissions, see the [permissions reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference).

You can read more on the changes for v2.x (which is enforced from April 30 1025) in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0) (such as deprecated permissions and endpoints).